# Paid Membership Pro

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to make a custom login area and registration area with subscription plans to be paid.
I used several plugins to design it. But I couldn't.
Then I installed Paid membership Pro Plugin and now, I can't understand how it works.

I  want to know to

1. How to make a login area.
2. How to make a registration area with selecting subscription plan. (Please be kind to post your answer with how to design a registration area even without selecting subscription plan.)
3. Does it saves the user login details.
4. how to design a page to edit the profile.
5. creating a payment gateway.

I wish you would know  answer any of the above questions. Please be kind to share your knwoledge.

Comment: Okay, but you can make your own registration process for your website using a plugin. For sure its doable and easy if you know what to do. Or you can employ somebody to  create that plugin for  you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better done when you employ someone to do it for you. There are lots of WordPress login & registration form... You can use any of them that works best with your theme.